# biometric authentication java aplication. how to build the connection between an smartphone and application

Tags: java, android, javafx, fingerprint

I have to develop an biometric authentication application.
The application will be written in java and it will be an desktop app, I want to use my smartphone for the fingerprint sensor, but I don`t know  how to build this connection betwenn application and phone. 
The main application will be installed on a computer without web.

I would be grateful if you have any idea or examples how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Your phone cannot share fingerprints with your desktop computer. That is, the fingerprint that your phone captures,cannot be moved "out of the phone". OTOH, if you want to use the phone for fingerprint capture _and_ matching on the phone, you may @Thiagesh's answer useful; the technical merits of such an approach, is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an app on your smartphone which uses the fingerprint authentication API.
If you are looking to use an android phone, you can refer this
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#fingerprint-authentication

You can create a simple APP using this API. 
When user authenticates, then you can send message to your desktop java application from this App. 
By 'without web' if you mean without internet, but can be connected to a local network, then you can send message via TCP/UDP.
Or if you wont be able to connect to any network, then you can try bluetooth.
If bluetooth is also not available, then you can connect your phone to your computer via a USB cable and communicate using Serial communication. There are a few external libraries available for this.